# English Words for online dictionary MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, dictionary, phpmyadmin

I'm just building an online dictionary English to malayalam, Malayalam to english dictionary.

Here is the link http://www.vanmaram.com/

That website offers the user the option to add words.

I would like to add some words.

If anyone knows where to get english words, could you please give me directions. 
It would be very helpful for me

Comment: @fivedigit I need English word list

Comment: @fivedigit then I can add appropriate Malayalam words

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are meany open dictionary files you can find on the internet, i would recommend using the ones from [open office](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Dictionaries#English_.28AU.2CCA.2CGB.2CNZ.2CUS.2CZA.29) or something like that. They also have a Malayalam one.

Open office allso refers to a more up to date list of data from [aspell.net](http://misc.aspell.net/wiki/English_Dictionaries).

Answer (score 2):

you can check this out too : [MySQL formatted english words list](http://www.4redpixels.com/uploads/words.sql)

dunno much about how many words are not in but it's a huge list anyway :)

There are about 128/129K words in